# View is not affecting on button click

Tags: model-view-controller

```
    $("#btntest").click(function () {
            alert('Called btn test');
            var FromDate = $("#FromDate").val();
            var ToDate = $("#ToDate").val();
            var UserId = $("#ddlUserName")[0].value;
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%:Url.Action("Grid1","GridView") %>',
                  data: '{"uid":"' + UserId + '","fdate": "' + FromDate + '","tdate":"' + ToDate + '"}',
                  type: "POST",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  success: function (data) {
                      alert('Success');
                      alert(data);
                      window.open("../GridView/Grid1");
                  }
              });

        });
```

on button click  GridView action have to call with its respective view(Grid1)

public ActionResult Grid1(string uid, string fdate, string tdate)
        {

```
        List<modeldata> list = new List<modeldata>();
        DataTable ds1 = new DataTable();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGettLeadReport", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", uid);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", fdate);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", tdate);



        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds1);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds1.Rows)
        {
            list.Add(new modeldata
            {
                LeadName = dr["LeadName"].ToString(),
                CompanyName = dr["CompanyName"].ToString(),
                CreatedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["CreatedOn"]),
                CreatedBy = dr["CreatedBy"].ToString(),
                //  ZoneName = dr["ZONE_NAME"].ToString()
            });
        }
        return View(list);
    }
```

View Is not affecting.on new window it throws an error..

how can i change to the corresponding action view?
please help..

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax code as below.

```
$.ajax({
                url: '<%:Url.Action("Click Here","Grid1","Controller Name") %>',
                  data: '{"uid":"' + UserId + '","fdate": "' + FromDate + '","tdate":"' + ToDate + '"}',
                  type: "POST",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  success: function (data) {
                      alert('Success');
                      alert(data);
                      window.open("../GridView/Grid1");
                  }
              });
```